# Hightlighting the top 10, records by order in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

Need help in highlighting the top 10 stores with the highest no. of sales

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline 
import seaborn as sns 

store = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/Kevin-ck1/Intro-To-Data-Science/blob/master/Clothing.csv")

store.head()
```

The variable name of the data set are as shown below

```
tsale   sales   margin  nown    nfull   npart   naux    hoursw  hourspw     inv1    inv2    ssize   start
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! We can do this by first finding the index of the top 10 stores. Once we do that, we apply a styling function to each row and check to see if the current row index (here stored in `row.name`) is in the previously identified index of the top 10 stores. If it is: we return a list that highlights that row, if not: we don't style that row at all.

```
def highlight_top(df, n=1):
    def _highlight_top(row, index):
        if row.name in index:
            return ["background-color: yellow" for _ in row]
        return ["" for _ in row]
    
    top_stores = df.nlargest(n, "sales")
    top_idx = top_stores.index.values
    return df.style.apply(_highlight_top, index=top_idx, axis=1)
    
# subset our data for testing purposes by only taking the first 10 rows
test_data = store.head(10)

# highlight the top 5 stores in terms of sales
highlight_top(test_data, n=5)
```

[image]

Comment: This is also what I would do. Another thought: `["background-color: yellow"] * len(row)` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

check your data:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 53, saw 2
```

look for the delimiter in a string.

you can also try:
**error_bad_lines=False** parameter in *read_csv*

Comment: the URL you are using is returning HTML.
there is a raw version available : 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kevin-ck1/Intro-To-Data-Science/master/Clothing.csv - which is working. The second part of your question is already answered.

Comment: @CameronRiddell, yeah just realised, the original data was from a shortened link, so had to upload the file to github so that i can share the problem to stack overflow